# regex with and without lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex

I have a string that can look like these examples:

1. `lookbehind text bla lookahead`
2. `lookbehind text bla`
3. `text bla lookahead`
4. `text bla`

How do I match in every case `text bla`?
`text bla` could be some string with whitespaces.

With regex `(?<=lookbehind\s)[\w\s]+(?=\slookahead)` it only works in case no. 1.

How to cover the other examples?

Comment: why not just text bla, it will match when the lookbehind and lookahead is there as well.

Comment: What's wrong with `/text bla/`?

Comment: well, actually its some string with whitespaces.. maybe bad example

Comment: yeah, but `text bla` could also be `hi whats up`.. and i don't want the lookbehind and lookahaed to be matched!

Comment: @user1451130 The only part of the string that is matched is the pattern `text bla`. Depending on whether you want the whole line matching returned or the tokens in the line matching returned, the end result will differ.

Comment: well I just want to match `text bla`. That's the problem I try to solve. I just want `text bla` in every case whether the is a lookbehind and or a lookahead. Is this even possible in one regex?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
^(?:.*lookbehind\s*)?((?:(?!\slookahead)[\w ])+)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?354st)

This is a bit more complicated, I found no simpler solution. The result is always in capturing group 1, since I am matching "lookbehind\s*" if it is there.

`^` Start of the string

`(?:lookbehind\s*)?` optional group, does match "lookbehind" with all following whitespaces.

Now there is the bit complicated part:

```
(                              # Start of the capturing group, stores the interesting part in group 1
    (?:                        # Non capturing group
        (?!\slookahead)[\w\s]  # Match [\w\s] only if it is not the start of the sequence "\slookahead"
    )+                         # repeat this
)
```

Comment: I tested this regex in RegexBuddy and it doesn't quite work for me. It is picking up the word "lookbehind" inside capture group 1.

Comment: Ok, that occurs, when "lookbehind" is not at the start of the string. Try this `^(?:.*lookbehind\s*)?((?:(?!\slookahead)[\w ])+)`

Comment: Your right. I had whitespaces at the beginning of my strings. Your new regex works on that too now.

Answer (score 2):

Following regex should work you:

```
(?:(?!lookbehind|lookahead)\b\w+\b| )+
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/rBB3GmgBec

Comment: This works. But the input string would have to be trimmed before running the regex on it. It is matching whitespaces that are before the lookbehind part. Not a big deal really.

Answer (score 0):

As a different approach, you could use a regex replace to remove all unwanted text (the lookbehind and lookahead parts).

```
\s*(?:lookbehind|lookahead)\s*
```

Here is an example in C#:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(testInput, @"\s*(?:lookbehind|lookahead)\s*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the look-arounds to match certain text *or* start/end:

```
(?<=((lookbehind)|^)\s*)text bla(?=\s*(lookahead)|$)
```